# Complex relations in database (with Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I want to know how to make relations between tables:

I have a `shops` table and a `users` table.
I want to associate to the `users` table: shops (id) AND area (that's a group of shops).
I don't know how to do that in a beautiful and right way.

For example, in a very complex way we can have:

Area A contains [Area B (3 shops) and Area C (1 shop)] and 1 shop : total of 5 shops.
John is associate to the Area A, Area X and 3 other shops (no area).

How to represent this in database?
It's like a recursive thing :(

Thanks by advance!

Comment: I would create these tables: USER, AREA, SHOP, AREA_TO_SHOP, AREA_TO_USER, SHOP_TO_USER

Comment: I think you'd want to implement the nested set pattern for the areas table which will give you a structure that supports having multiple nested areas going as deep as you need.   https://github.com/etrepat/baum  Using that, you should just need a `users` table, `areas` table, and `shops` table.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to have the following tables:

```
users
  - id
  - username

shops
  - id
  - name

areas
  - id
  - name
  - parent_id

user_shop
  - user_id
  - shop_id

area_shop
  - shop_id
  - area_id
```

Then for your example, a row might look like

```
users
  id: 1
  username: jappleseed

shops
  id: 1
  name: some shop name

  id: 2
  name: some other shop name

areas
  id: 1
  name: Area A
  parent_id: null

  id: 2
  name: Area B
  parent_id: 1

  id: 3
  name: Area C
  parent_id: 1

area_shop
  area_id: 2
  shop_id: 1

  area_id: 2
  shop_id: 2
```

Then you could define your relationship for nested areas like:

```
class Area extends Model {

    /**
     * Parent Area
     */
    public function parent_area()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Area', 'parent_id');
    }

    /**
     * Child Areas
     */
    public function child_areas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Area', 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

The other relationships should be fairly straight forward.

This is untested and might need a little tweaking, but the overarching idea should get you there.  Otherwise, using a prebuilt nested set library would also work.